# Keeping the current tabs after submitting the form

Tags: jquery, tabs

I know this question was asked before by many people but I didn't get the solution and i'm not really good in Jquery so, what i did is that i implemented tabs in my page and eache one has a form but when i click on the button of the second the page give me the first tab after reloading. This is my Code jquery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
      $('#tab-container').easytabs();
    });
  </script>
```

What I have is exactlly what is in this page demo :http://jspkg.com/packages/easytabs/demos

How can i resolve the problem ?

Comment: i think you can use "active" class to choose which tab be selected.

Comment: Also you can submit forms with ajax, that way page won't refresh.

Comment: When I just refresh the page the tab is keeping but not when i submit the form. the id of the tab is added to the link of my page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either improve your HTML/ HTTP post structure:

1. Set a hidden field in your FORM, to specify which tab is selected.
2. Use the resulting request parameter server-side, to
3. Select the correct tab to show in the round-tripped result page.

(If you have one FORM for the whole page, you can set the value of that on the tab `select` event.. if you have one form per tab, it's just a constant.)

```
$('#tab-container').easytabs(
    defaultTab: '${defaultTab_Selector}'
);
```

If you're using MVC and JSP, you'd set "defaultTab_Selector" to be a selector to find the `<li>` of the tab. (I use jQuery UI Tabs, which just uses a numeric index to do this bit.)

In Spring MVC, if your second tab is `<li id='tab2'>`:

```
ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("gestion_user");
mv.addObject( "defaultTab_Selector", "#tab2");
return mv;
```

Or post by AJAX.

Comment: If i choose the first solution, the hidden fild need to set method of the form to GET however i want to send the form by POST, cause i don't want to show informations in the adress bar. also the project is a spring project, that make it a little complicate

Comment: You can make the server understand whatever you send it, but the best method is to name the field `selectedTab` & have the server check that parameter. Either POST or GET will work fine -- as you say, POST hides the parameters.

Comment: I added the hidden field but how to link it with the script of jquery tabs?

Comment: What if i add the id of tabs in the name of view inside the controller?? because when i click on the first tab i get this URL : **http://localhost:8080/GestionDelegation/gestion_user#tabs-add**
and the second : 

**http://localhost:8080/GestionDelegation/gestion_user#tabs-update**

The name of view is gestion_user and usually the controller return this name, so how to add the id of tab to return statement??
Is that possible??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$('#tab-container').easyTabs({ updateHash: false });